# Pyspark preserving the order of fields when converting dataframe rows to dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe df with below data:

```
Name        Value     Code
a           1         1
b           2         1
c           3         2
d           4         2
```

I want to convert this dataframe to a dictionary. I tried using asDict():

```
 map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect())
```

and it is giving the following output:

```
[{'Code': 1, 'Name': u'a', 'Value': 1}, {'Code': 1, 'Name': u'b', 'Value': 2}, {'Code': 2, 'Name': u'c', 'Value': 3}, {'Code': 2, 'Name': u'd', 'Value': 4}]
```

Here the fields are sorted. But I want to preserve the order of the fields.

My output should look this:

```
[{'Name': u'a', 'Value': 1,'Code': 1}, {'Name': u'b', 'Value': 2,'Code': 1}, {''Name': u'c', 'Value': 3,Code': 2}, {'Name': u'd', 'Value': 4,'Code': 2}]
```

Is there any other way to achieve this other than using asDict() method?

Answer (score 0):

In python a `dict` doesn't have any notion of order. You need to use `OrderedDict` for that. You could do something like this

```
from collections import OrderedDict
...
map(lambda row: OrderedDict(zip(df.columns, list(row))), df.collect())
```